# How to get multiple virtual field data in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I want two virtual field to be merged in the fetching records.But i have done it for only one virtual field,another one is returning null.

I am quite confuse how to return two virtual field data.For one its coming fine.

Below is the codes
In model/Entity/Order.php

```html
protected $_virtual = ['due','paid'];


    protected function _getDue() {
        return $this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
         return $this->_properties['collection']['total_sale_amount']-$this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
    }
```

Below is the output

```html
[
    {
          "id": 20,
          "collection": {
            "id": 150,
            "order_id": 20,
            "total_sale_amount": 110,
            "net_paid": 10,
            "due_amount": 70,
            "is_paid": 1,
            "payment_mode": "DD",
            "reference_num": "",
            "created": "2016-09-09T00:00:00+0000"
        },
        "due": 70,
        "paid": null
    }
]
```

Here paid is coming null,but is should come 110-70 = 40 .

if i am keeping any one instead of 2 ,i am getting what i supposed to need.

Please suggest me.
any suggestion will be highly appreciated .
:)

Comment: You cannot write two return in a single function. second statement will never execute.

Comment: @Ravi Hirani  yes i know ,it won't work.
But is there any way ,so that i can get two result at a time.

Comment: make another function and write second statement into it. because you are using return value. OR in a single function, return an array and put bot values in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mentioned in comment, you cannot write two returns in a single function.

You should use an array. put both values inside array and return an array.

```
 protected function _getDue() {
    $data = [];
    $data['due'] = $this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
    $data['paid'] = $this->_properties['collection']['total_sale_amount']-$this->_properties['collection']['due_amount'];
    return $data;
 }
```

Comment: Yes i got it.
Thank you a lot .
Its the silly things i am asking here.